# Do functions with vertical asymptotes necessarily have infinite derivatives for all degrees?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Suppose I have a function $f(x)$ where $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$.

- First take $n = 1$. Now suppose that there exists a point $\bar x$ where the $d$th derivative $f^d(\bar x)$ is defined and is finite for some $d \geq 1$. Does this necessarily imply that $f(\bar x)$ is defined and is finite, or is it possible that it is undefined or infinite?

(The example I am trying to construct is something like: $f(0) = 0$, $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x) = +\infty$. (So it is defined, it just isn't finite.) We can also assume that $f(x) \geq 0$ for $0 \leq x < 1$, to help at least with the $d=1$ case. Now $f^d(x)$ is defined and finite for all $x < 1$. But, is it necessary that $f^d(x)\overset{x\to 1}{\to} +\infty$ for all $d$ as well?)

- Now suppose $n > 1$, and suppose $\mathcal C\subset \mathbb R^n$ is a closed connected set.
  I know that for some $\bar x\in \mathcal C$, $f(\bar x) = 0$, and I also know that for all $x\in \mathcal C$,  for *some* $u$, $u^T\nabla f(x) u$ is finite. Does this necessarily mean that $f(x)$ is finite for all $x\in \mathcal C$?

This seems like a basic result, but I'm fearful of potential counterexamples.

**Edit**: the more that I think about it, the more I think that it is true in $n = 1$, but can't be true in $n > 1$.

- For $n = 1$, it seems like if $f(x)$ is finite-valued for all $x \in [0,1)$, then the only way that $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x) = +\infty$ is if all its derivatives go to $+\infty$ at $x\to 1$.
- For $n > 1$, the simple counterexample of
  $$
  \nabla^2 f(x) = \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/(1-x_2) \end{matrix}\right]
  $$
  seems to satisfy the bill.

Comment: If $f$ is not defined at $x=1$ then neither are any of its derivatives.

Comment: Do you want to ask instead about the *limit* of $f^{(d)}(x)$ as $x \to 1$?

Comment: You say $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ and then say $f(1)$ is not defined.

Comment: I reframed the problem to ask in terms of counterexamples. I guess my question is about a point whose value is $+\infty$, and questioning whether the "laws of undefined-ness" are still valid. Like I said, seems like a simple thing but I just want to make sure there aren't any loose counterexamples.

Comment: I also modified the multivariate case a little. The tricky thing is that there is only one $u$ where we are sure that $u^T\nabla^2 f(x)u$ is finite. The other directions are left unspecified.

Comment: I'm tempted to do it by integration, but it's not clear to me that something whose integral is $+\infty$ is itself $+\infty$.  And I'm also not sure if we can assume monotonicity, which would be needed to imply the reverse.

Comment: I will add the assumption that at the very least, we can assume that $f(x) \geq 0$ for $x \in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if $d=1$ it is possible for $\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)= \infty,$
while $\lim_{x\to 1^-}f'(x)=\infty$ fails. Consider the example

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} + \sin(1/(1-x)).$$

Then $\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)= \infty.$ But

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}(1+\cos(1/(1-x)).$$

Along the sequence $x_n= 1-1/[(2n+1)\pi]$ we have $f'(x_n)=0$ for all $n.$

Comment: Very cool example. A bit weird because you have to be on that sequence, but definitely works.